# Consuming REST Webservice in Xamarin whilst debugging on Android phone

Tags: android, visual-studio, rest, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am running into problems consuming a rest web service hosted on Azure in an Android Xamarin Application.

```
async Task ViewTimetableAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DependencyService.Get<ITimetableService>().GetTimetableAsync(_user);
}
```

This is the code that is called in the XAML.cs class, it is a button event.

```
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = "Fail";
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var reson = e.Data;
}
```

This is the relevant code that is being used to call the REST web service. The code is hanging when GetAsync is called. No error is thrown, don't get any discernible information in the output.

I have included internet as a required permission in the Android manifest. I have included System.net.http as a NuGet package.

I am getting no traffic in Azure, so it is clearly not even reaching the web service. So why is this Http Client not sending the request? I am having to debug on an Android phone connected by USB using Visual Studio, and that seems to be running fine, the only issue being the inability to send out this request. The API is accessible from the phone as I brought it up in a browser, is it a setting in the phone itself that is possibly causing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Postman?

Comment: Postman on the phone? I am able to access the web API successfully from the phone, it is only when GetAsync is called from inside the Xamarin application that I run into problems. The API is not getting hit at all by the application, but is from my computer and the phone browser looking at the traffic I am getting in the Azure dashboard.

Comment: No, by using the (Postman) application itself. If it is working, you can try implementing a basic `HttpClient` implementation without the use of `NativeMessageHandler`, cause I have an application without the use of it and it's working fine, both `Post` and `Get`.